# Good Python with statement explanation

Tags: python, with-statement

I've tried google and other places but I can't seem to find a good explanation of the `with` statement. In what situations is it useful? I get how it works with files but how else could it be used?

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: I don't know what you searched for, but ["python with statement"](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+with+statement) yields quite good results for me.

Comment: What don't you understand? What have you tried? Have you read the docs? How about this? http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good example:

```
  class controlled_execution:
            def __enter__(self):
                set things up
                return thing
            def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
                tear things down

        with controlled_execution() as thing:
             some code
```

When the “with” statement is executed, Python evaluates the expression, calls the **enter** method on the resulting value (which is called a “context guard”), and assigns whatever **enter** returns to the variable given by as. Python will then execute the code body, and no matter what happens in that code, call the guard object’s **exit** method.

Comment: This is copied from [source](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) -- both, the source code and the explanation.  The source code on effbot is in the public domain, but it's [not allowed to republish the articles itself](http://effbot.org/zone/copyright.htm).  Since this is only a single paragraph, it might qualify as fair use, but this would at least reuire a reference.

Comment: It was never under the context of my own work, in fact it explicitly says a good example.

Comment: @OnResolve: It doesn't say **whose** example. That means it could very well be yours, even if you don't say that it is. And in this case, evidence shows that it's not yours. Now, I'm not pointing fingers here; I'm simply trying to clarify something that might otherwise be misinterpreted.